# How to select all nodes beetwen certain headers?

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

Each `<header>` tag contains a Title of Conference.
Each `<ul>` tag contains the links of this conference.

When I'll to try to crawl the website, I'm try to associating the `<header>` tag with yours links in `<ul>` tags. But I don't know how I can only select the `<ul>` tags of are sibling two certain `<headers>`.

HTML:

```
<header>... 0 ... </header>
<ul class="publ-list">... 0 ...</ul>
<header>... 1 ... </header> 
<ul class="publ-list">... 0 ...</ul>
<header>... 2 ... </header>
<ul class="publ-list">... 0 ...</ul>
<p>...</p>
<ul class="publ-list">... 1 ...</ul>
<header>... 3 ...</header>
<ul class="publ-list">... 0 ...</ul>
<ul class="publ-list">... 1 ...</ul>
<ul class="publ-list">... 2 ....</ul>
<ul class="publ-list">... 3 ....</ul>
<ul class="publ-list">... 4 ....</ul>
<header>... 4 ...</header>
```

Example:

- `<ul>` tags are sibling of header[0] and header[1]

  ```
  <ul class="publ-list">... 0 ...</ul>
  ```
- `<ul>` tags are sibling of header[2] and header[3]

  ```
  <ul class="publ-list">... 0 ...</ul>
  <ul class="publ-list">... 1 ...</ul>
  ```

Some cases:

- It's possible more than one ul tag between header tag
- Sometimes has a p tag between ul tags
- All tags are siblings!
- All ul has class "publ-list"

**My code:**

```
TITLE_OF_EDITIONS_SELECTIOR = 'header h2'
GROUP_OF_TYPES_OF_EDITION_SELECTOR = ".publ-list"

size_editions = len(response.css(GROUP_OF_TYPES_OF_EDITION_SELECTOR))
i = 0
while i < size_editions:

    # Get the title of conference
    title_edition_conference = response.css(TITLE_OF_EDITIONS_SELECTIOR)[i]


    # Get datas and links of <ul> tags "(.publ-list)"
    TYPES_OF_CONFERENCE = response.css(GROUP_OF_TYPES_OF_EDITION_SELECTOR)[i]
    TYPE = TYPES_OF_CONFERENCE.css('.entry')
    types_of_edition = {}
    size_type_editions = 0
    for type_of_conference in TYPE:
        title_type = type_of_conference.css('.data .title ::text').extract()
        link_type = type_of_conference.css('.publ ul .drop-down .body ul li a ::attr(href)').extract_first()
        types_of_edition[size_type_editions] = {
            "title": title_type,
            "link": link_type,
            }
        size_type_editions = size_type_editions + 1

    editions[i] = {
        "title_edition_conference": title_edition_conference,
        "types_of_edition": types_of_edition
        }
    i = i + 1
```

**Problem of My Code**

- Sometimes there are many ul tags
- Sometimes has a `<p>` tag and it's break my xPath, and get only the previous `<ul>` tags.

I got it testing with JQuery on Console of Google Chrome, example:

```
"$($('header')[0]).nextUntil($('header')[1])"
```

But How I can select this using xPath or CSS Selector? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following combination of `css` selectors and python `for` loop can solve this task.

```
from parsel import Selector

html  = """
<ul class="publ-list">p1</ul>
<header>h1</header>
<ul class="publ-list">p2</ul>
<header>h2</header>
<ul class="publ-list">p3</ul>
<header>h3</header>
<ul class="publ-list">p4</ul>
<p>p_tag_1</p>
<ul class="publ-list">p5</ul>
<header>h4</header>
<ul class="publ-list">p6</ul>
<ul class="publ-list">p7</ul>
<header>h5</header>
<ul class="publ-list">p8</ul>
"""
response = Selector(text=html)
tags = response.css("header, ul")
output = {}
key = False
for t in tags:
    if key and "<ul" in t.css("*").extract_first():
        output[key].append(t.css("::text").extract_first())
    elif "<header>" in t.css("*").extract_first():
        key = t.css("::text").extract_first()
        if key not in output.keys():
            output[key]=[]
    else:
        pass
print(output)
```

Output is:
`{'h1': ['p2'], 'h2': ['p3'], 'h3': ['p4', 'p5'], 'h4': ['p6', 'p7'], 'h5': ['p8']}`

This css selector: `tags = response.css("header, ul")` returns list of `<header>` and `<ul>` tags in the same order as in the html code.

After that we can iterate through received tags using `for` loop and select required data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `following-sibling` like here:

```
>>> txt = """<header>..</header>
... <ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
... <header>..</header>
... <ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
... <header>..</header>
... <ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
... <p>...</p>
... <ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
... <header>..</header>
... <ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
... <ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
... <header>..</header>"""
>>> from scrapy import Selector
>>> sel = Selector(text=txt)
>>> sel.xpath('//header/following-sibling::*[not(self::header)]').extract()
[u'<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>', u'<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>', u'<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>', u'<p>...</p>', u'<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>', u'<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>', u'<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>']
```

So with `//header/following-sibling::*[not(self::header)]` we choose all `header` siblings, but not `header`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. I would just like the ul of certain headers. Like, select only ul's between header[0] and header[1]. I got it using/testing with JQuery, example: "$($('header')[0]).nextUntil($('header')[1])". But I have no ideia how to implement this with xPath.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for.

```
html = """
<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
<header>..</header>
<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
<header>..</header>
<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
<header>..</header>
<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
<p>...</p>
<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
<header>..</header>
<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
<header>..</header>
<ul class="publ-list">...</ul>
"""
```

Note I added a `<ul>`before the first and after the last `<header>..</header>` sets.

This expression

```
 //ul[   
preceding-sibling::header 
    and 
following-sibling::header
   ]
```

should select all the `<ul>` tags, except those I added before and after, and none of the `<p>` tags which may be in the way.

Comment: Not yet, I need to know whats <ul> tags are siblings of two headers, because in my real problem I need to associating the first <header> tag which contain a title with next <ul> tags The second <header> tag with next <ul> tags and so on... 
I'm your xPath i don't know which ul tags are sibling of two headers tags.

Comment: @thiagoheron - Then you should edit your question to clarify all that, and add more code to illustrate the problem